# Filtering a data frame

Tags: r, select, filter

I have read in a csv file in matrix form (having m rows and n columns). I want to filter the matrix by conducting a filter in verbal form:

Select all values from column x where the values of an another column in this row is equal to "blabla".

It is like a select statement in database where I say I am interested in a subset of the matrix where these constraints need to be satisfied.

How can I do it in r? I have the data as dataframe and can access it by the headers. `data["column_values" = "15"]` does not give me back the rows where the column named column_values have values 15 only.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You said you just wanted the column x values where column_values was 15, right?

```
subset(dat, column_values==15, select=x)
```

I think this may come as a dataframe so it's possble you may need to unlist() it and maybe even "unfactor" it.

```
> dat
  Subject Product
1       1   ProdA
2       1   ProdB
3       1   ProdC
4       2   ProdB
5       2   ProdC
6       2   ProdD
7       3   ProdA
8       3   ProdB
> subset(dat, Subject==2, Product)
  Product
4   ProdB
5   ProdC
6   ProdD
> unlist( subset(dat, Subject==2, Product) )
Product1 Product2 Product3 
   ProdB    ProdC    ProdD 
Levels: ProdA ProdB ProdC ProdD
> as.character( unlist( subset(dat, Subject==2, Product) ) )
[1] "ProdB" "ProdC" "ProdD"
```

If you want all of the columns you can drop the third argument (the select= argument):

```
subset(dat, Subject==2 )

  Subject Product
4       2   ProdB
5       2   ProdC
6       2   ProdD
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Actually I want to have the whole subset back, I mean also with other columns. can you please show me how I can have the result 2 Prod B; 2 ProdC; 2 ProdC back? In my case, I want to filter over more than one column like Jack showed. But it is still not working. can you see the error? Thanks!

Comment: Posted an edit. You can specify any combination of factors in a vector of either quoted or unquoted column names. `subset` is also going to omit all those annoying NA matches that I hate and other people appreciate.

Comment: I tried subset(data, V1=="stochastic", V6=="independent"). But it is not working. V1 and V6 are two column headers. The result back is > subset(data, V1=="stochastic", V6=="independent")
data frame with 0 columns and 196 rows
Why am I not getting the whole data in its initial form back but only the rows where the v1 and v6 are satisfied?

Comment: Perhaps:  subset(data, V1=="stochastic" & V6=="independent") . Maybe you can post dput(head(data))?

Comment: for unfactoring variables in R you can use the function unfactor() in [varhandle](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/varhandle/) package

Comment: No need for obscure packages. The canonical method for "unfactoring" in R is with `as.character()`.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that `dat` is the data frame in question, `col` is the name of the column and `"value"` is the value that you want, you can do

`dat[dat$col=="value",]`

That fetches all of the rows of `dat` for which `dat$col=="value"`, and all of the columns.

Comment: how can I select over two columns? One column is working fine. For example, I tried this data[data$V1=="stochastic",data$V6=="independent",] how can I realize and operation while selecting over two columns?

Comment: `data[data$V1=="stochastic" && data$V6=="independent",]`

Comment: data[data$V1=="stochastic" && data$V6=="stochastic",]
 [1] V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

it doesn't show the result. I am sure that the result is not empty. Any idea?

Comment: Oops, sorry, try `data[data$V1=="stochastic" & data$V6=="independent",]`.  I keep forgetting that R, unlike almost every other language on the planet, uses `&` to mean what most other languages mean by `&&` (http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/R/html/base/html/Logic.html).

Comment: Maybe. depends on meaning. Use the OR or AND operator which for parallel operations like this is "|" or "&".

Comment: `df=as.data.frame(cbind(1:5,6:10,11:15))`
`df[df$V1==3 & df$V2==8,]`
Produces the correct data (namely the row represented by the tuple `(3,8,13)`).

Comment: Regardless, you can always use the `subset` function, as per Dwin's answer below.  If you really need a ton of (SQL-equivalent) `where` conditions, though, you might want to consider cleaning your data before importing it into R.

Answer (score 4):

First, note that a `matrix` and a `data.frame` are different things in R.  I imagine you have a `data.frame` (as that is what is returned by `read.csv()`).  `data.frame`'s have named columns (if you don't give them ones, generic ones are created for you).

You can subset a `data.frame` by indicating both what rows you want and/or what columns you want.  The easiest way to specify which rows is with a logical vector, often built out of comparisons using specific columns of the `data.frame`.  For example `data[["column values"]] == "15"` would make a logical vector which is `TRUE` if the corresponding entry in the column `column values` is the string "15" (since it is in quotes, it is a string, not a number).  You can make as complicated a selection criteria as you like (combining logical vectors with `&` and `|`) to specify the rows you want.  This vector becomes the first argument in the indexing.

A list of column names or numbers can be the second argument.  If either argument is missing, all rows (or columns) are assumed.

Putting this all together, you get examples like

```
data[data[["column values"]] == "15", ]
```

or using an actual data set (`mtcars`)

```
mtcars[mtcars$am == 1, ]
mtcars[mtcars$am == 1 & mtcars$hp > 100, "mpg"]
mtcars[mtcars$am == 1 & mtcars$hp > 100, "mpg", drop=FALSE]
mtcars[mtcars$hp > 100, c("mpg", "carb")]
```

Take a look at what each of the conditionals (first arguments, e.g. `mtcars$am == 1 & mtcars$hp > 100`) return to get a better sense of how indexing works.